# vim : expand in :h

Tags: vim

how I can use expand in the vim help file, similar to this

```
 :h expand('%:t:r').'-content'
```

I get

```
 E149: Sorry, no help for expand('%:t:r').'-content'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your string and pass it to [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3aexe):

```
:exe 'h '.expand('%:t:r').'-content'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of accomplishing this effect is via the expression register or `<c-r>=` followed by an expression.

```
:h <c-r>=expand('%:t:r').'-content'<cr><cr>
```

`<c-r>` followed by a register will insert the contents of a register in both insert and command mode. The `=` register is a special register that will execute an expression and return its value. A common use of this expression register is doing math. e.g. `<c-r>=2+2<cr>`

For more help see:

```
:h c_CTRL-R=
:h quote_=
:h c_CTRL-R
:h i_CTRL-R
```